# JWT-auth returning 401 error on login

Tags: php, laravel-5, jwt, http-status-code-401

JWT-auth keeps returning 401 error on login. The credentials are correct, I even went as far as changing the encrypted password to the plain password in the db and it still returned 401. The register method works just fine, I haven't gotten to the other methods just yet.

For reference here is my code:
**Note, my users are in a table called `consumers`**

**Consumer migration**

```
class CreateConsumerTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('consumers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('con_id', 11);
            $table->string('con_fname', 50);
            $table->string('con_lname', 50);
            $table->string('email', 50);
            $table->string('password', 100);
            $table->binary('con_cover_photo')->nullable();
            $table->binary('con_profile_pic')->nullable();
            $table->double('total_earned', 10, 2)->default('0');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('consumers');
    }
}
```

**user_verification migration**

```
class CreateUserVerificationsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
      Schema::create('user_verifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments('id');
           $table->integer('con_id')->unsigned();
           $table->string('token');
           $table->foreign('con_id')->references('con_id')->on('consumers');//->onDelete('cascade');//onUpdate();
      });
      Schema::table('consumers', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->boolean('is_verified')->default(0);
      });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('user_verifications');

        Schema::table('consumers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('is_verified');
        });
    }
}
```

**AuthController.php (register, verifyUSer and login methods only**

```
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('con_fname', 'con_lname', 'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation');

        $rules = [
            'con_fname' => 'required|max:255',
            'con_lname' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:consumers',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'same:password'
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($credentials, $rules);
        if($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['success'=> false, 'error'=> $validator->messages()]);
        }

        $fname = $request->con_fname;
        $lname = $request ->con_lname;
        $email = $request->email;
        $password = $request->password;

        $user = Consumer::create(['con_fname' => $fname, 'con_lname' => $lname, 'email' => $email, 'password' => Hash::make($password)]);
        $verification_code = str_random(30); //Generate verification code
        DB::table('user_verifications')->insert(['con_id'=>$user->con_id,'token'=>$verification_code]);
        $subject = "Please verify your email address.";
        Mail::send('email.verify', ['con_fname' => $fname, 'con_lname' => $lname, 'verification_code' => $verification_code],
            function($mail) use ($email, $fname, $subject){
                $mail->from(getenv('FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS'), "From User/Company Name Goes Here");
                $mail->to($email);
                $mail->subject($subject);
            });
        return response()->json(['success'=> true, 'message'=> 'Thanks for signing up! Please check your email to complete your registration.']);
    }

    public function verifyUser($verification_code)
  {
      $check = DB::table('user_verifications')->where('token',$verification_code)->first();
      if(!is_null($check)){
          $user = Consumer::find($check->con_id);
          if($user->is_verified == 1){
              return response()->json([
                  'success'=> true,
                  'message'=> 'Account already verified..'
              ]);
          }
          $user->update(['is_verified' => 1]);
          DB::table('user_verifications')->where('token',$verification_code)->delete();
          return response()->json([
              'success'=> true,
              'message'=> 'You have successfully verified your email address.'
          ]);
      }
      return response()->json(['success'=> false, 'error'=> "Verification code is invalid."]);
  }

  public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($credentials, $rules);
        if($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['success'=> false, 'error'=> $validator->messages()]);
        }

        $credentials['is_verified'] = 1;

        try {
            // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Invalid username or password'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Failed to login, please try again.'], 500);
        }
        // all good so return the token
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'data'=> [ 'token' => $token ]]);
    }
    /**
     * Log out
     * Invalidate the token, so user cannot use it anymore
     * They have to relogin to get a new token
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
}
```

**jwt.php**

return [

```
'secret' => env('JWT_SECRET'),

'keys' => [

    'public' => env('JWT_PUBLIC_KEY'),
    'private' => env('JWT_PRIVATE_KEY'),
    'passphrase' => env('JWT_PASSPHRASE'),

],

'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 60),
'refresh_ttl' => env('JWT_REFRESH_TTL', 20160),
'algo' => env('JWT_ALGO', 'HS256'),
'required_claims' => [
    'iss',
    'iat',
    'exp',
    'nbf',
    'sub',
    'jti',
],
'persistent_claims' => [
    // 'foo',
    // 'bar',
],
'blacklist_enabled' => env('JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED', true),

'blacklist_grace_period' => env('JWT_BLACKLIST_GRACE_PERIOD', 0),

'providers' => [

    'jwt' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Namshi::class,

    'auth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\Illuminate::class,

    'storage' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Storage\Illuminate::class,

],
```

];

Comment: what is your jwt config? did you change user model correctly?

Comment: i updated the answer to show my jwt.php. what do you mean by change my user model correctly? I believe I did.

Comment: Please add your JWT authentication class code.

Comment: and add auth config as well, have to check if the guard implemented correctly

Comment: @Ben  the auth config didnt have changes. running the commands generated a jwt config file (jwt.php)

Comment: @WalterWhite by jwt authentication class code im confused. I set up my authcontroller.php (my controller), jwt config (jwt.php), a blade file,  a migration file, as well as updated my routes. I dont have a jwt authentication class, not that I made at least. may it have auto generated when adding it to composer?

Comment: then you will need to change the api auth driver to jwt (http://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/#configure-auth-guard)

Comment: Thanks @Ben I'm just at work at the moment. Ill give it a shot when I get home. I changed the driver from `'token'` to `'jwt'`. It hadn't worked yet but Ill go over the documentation when I finish.